# C# ThreadPool ManualResetEvent without n instances of thread class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use `ManualResetEvent` to verify if all threads in my `ThreadPool` have completed. But according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx I need to have as many instances of my thread class as there are threads so that I can have a `ManualResetEvent` variable in each class and set it when the thread completes.

What if I have only one instance of the thread class and have to check if all threads executing a function of that instance have completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can know/determine the number of threads that will execute you can use a counter in that one class then set the single ManualResetEvent once the counter reaches the expected number.

Answer (score 1):

An idea could be using Interlocked: Use interlocked increment an a static variable of the class when you enter the function, and Interlocked.Decrement when the function finish. When you reach zero you know there is no more functions working.

Comment: What if one thread enters and exits the function before the next one does? Then the interlocked variable would reach zero before all threads have executed the function.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPool works like this: if the job is done then assign new job to the thread that was already created. I don't really know if that raises this event - you can do a simple test. Nevertheless you'll have to know how many jobs are there and if this mechanism doesn't work then you can simply create your own one..